# Json Decode or Xml Parser

Tags: php, xml, json

I am using

PHP Version 5.2.17

I am trying to decode json link and also tried simplexml_load_file For two different links but nothing is working .

As on local Server I have PHP 5.3 and all working fine.

Is there is any other way to work in php5.2.17 
Thanks

Comment: post sample data of what you want to parse. thx. also, see [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode)

Answer (score -2):

Did you use shortcuts on your local server? i.E. `< ?=$variable >` won't work in 5.2.